# Prove the continuity of this function in two variables

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{2xy^2}{x^2+y} & (x, y) \neq (0, 0) \\\\ 0 & (x, y) = (0, 0) \end{cases}$$

I have to check if $f$ is continuous at the origin, if the partial derivatives do exist and if they are continuous and if $f$ is differentiable at the origin.

I'm stuck on the continuity for I tried several paths and the limit returns always zero. Hence with this hope I started to prove the continuity with majorisations, but I got stuck. Here is what I tried:

$$\left| \dfrac{2xy^2}{x^2+y} \right| \leq \dfrac{2y^2 |x|}{x^2 + |y|} \leq \dfrac{2y^2 \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x^2 + y^2}$$

I did this because in the range $y \to 0$, we have $y > y^2$ hence the estimation holds.
Now:

$$\dfrac{2y^2 \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x^2 + y^2} \leq \dfrac{2(y^2+x^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x^2+y^2} = 2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\  \to 0\  \text{as}\ x^2+y^2 \to 0$$

Can this be a good way to proceed? Thank you!

**Adding**

I checked for the existence of the partial derivatives, and they do exist at the origin and they are both zero.

Now I have problems in the continuity.

For example:

$$f_x(x, y) = -2\dfrac{y^2(x^2-y)}{(x^2+y)^2}$$

I tried to use some majorisation after trying some path (which always returned zero), but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: $|\frac{1}{x^2 + y}| \not\leq \frac{1}{x^2 + |y|}$

Comment: @athalhaids Ouch!

Comment: Note that the upper branch of your definition for $f(x,y)$ fails to exist if $x^2+y=0$.  This can happen in a neighborhood of the point $(0,0)$.  Perhaps check your source for this exercise.

Comment: @hardmath The source of this is our professor who gave it to us as an additional exercise to try ourselves the definition... There is no solution for now

Comment: @hardmath Perhaps it was a typo, and it should have been $x^2+y^2$...

Comment: That would be my guess...

Comment: @hardmath Thank you! I'll email him and I'll let you know!

Comment: $\lim_{x\to0}f(x,-x^2+x^6)$ does not exist. Same guess as Numb3rs and hardmath. I think you can delete this post.

Comment: If it was a typo and it should have been $x^2+y^2$ instead of $x^2+y$, then $$\left|\dfrac{2xy^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|=\dfrac{\big(2|xy|\big)|y|}{x^2+y^2}\leqslant\dfrac{\left(x^2+y^2\right)|y|}{x^2+y^2}=|y|\underset{\color{blue}{(x,y)\to(0,0)}}{\longrightarrow}0\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{2xy^2}{x^2+y}=2xy \frac{\frac{y}{x^2}}{1+\frac{y}{x^2}}$. This helps to find the limit in  (0,0).
May be the same helps for derivative.